# Convert line break to '\n'

Tags: awk

I am trying to convert line breaks to literal '\n' characters.

Input file:

```
[root@centos8 test]# cat source/bla.md
---
title: Bla die ba 2
type: celix-doc
---

# Title
Descripripo

## Badf
dfg
```

Using awk I extract the content between the tripple dashes.

```
[root@centos8 test]# awk '/---/{++c;next} c==1' source/bla.md
title: Bla die ba 2
type: celix-doc
```

Is there a way to get this with '\n' characters instead of line breaks?

```
title: Bla die ba 2\ntype: celix-doc
```

This because I want to use this as input for `sed`, which currently fails because of the line breaks `sed -i "s/${original_header}/${new_header}/" ${DEST_FILE}`:

```
s/title: Bla die ba 2
type: celix-doc/title: Bla die ba 2
type: celix-doc\nversion: 24/
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: unterminated `s' command
```

Thanks already!

Comment: Have you tried changing `ORS`?

Comment: Your output has not  `\n` instead of __all__ newlines, but only for the first one.

Comment: What is the reason for this replacement?

Comment: @thanasisp I want to use this as input for `sed`: `sed -i "s/${original_header}/${new_header}/" ${DEST_FILE}`. Edited my the post to describe this.

Comment: @oguzismail thanks!! This works. As @thanasisp describes this indeed replaces **all** linebreaks, but this is something I am okay with. The command that worked for me was: `awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\\n";}/---/{++c;next} c==1' source/bla.md` resulting in the following: `title: Bla die ba 2\ntype: celix-doc\n`. I tried `RS` already but that didn't work.

Comment: Well done solving it on your own. Consider posting that as an answer and accepting two days later

Comment: There is no reason to to use both `awk` (to find) and `sed` (to replace). You should use one `awk` (or `sed`) command to find and replace.

Comment: @RoyLenferink if you run the script in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62979384/convert-line-break-to-n/62982393#comment111372922_62979384) tnen the output will not be a POSIX text file and so whatever any subsequent tool does with it would be undefined behavior. Don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

I THINK what you're trying to do is replace newline with `\n` inside `---`-separated records. If so then consider this with GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)---\n|\n$' -F'\n' -v OFS='\\n' '{ORS=RT; $1=$1} 1' file
---
title: Bla die ba 2\ntype: celix-doc
---
\n# Title\nDescripripo\n\n## Badf\ndfg
```

You can select/print one record at a time:

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)---\n|\n$' -F'\n' -v OFS='\\n' '{ORS=RT; $1=$1} NR==1' file
---

$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)---\n|\n$' -F'\n' -v OFS='\\n' '{ORS=RT; $1=$1} NR==2' file
title: Bla die ba 2\ntype: celix-doc
---

$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)---\n|\n$' -F'\n' -v OFS='\\n' '{ORS=RT; $1=$1} NR==3' file
\n# Title\nDescripripo\n\n## Badf\ndfg
```

and what I think you specifically want for output which is to just print a newline at the end of the 2nd record instead of the original `---` after modifying it:

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)---\n|\n$' -F'\n' -v OFS='\\n' '{$1=$1} NR==2' file
title: Bla die ba 2\ntype: celix-doc
```

As for `This because I want to use this as input for sed` - no, you definitely do not want to do that. You never need sed when you're using awk. If you post a new question with a more complete picture of what you're trying to do that you thing needs awk piping to sed then we can help you do whatever it is you're trying to do the right way.